# Unrecognized option: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, dockerfile

so i'm trying to make a docker container with tomcat work. I created a Dockerfile with this config :

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN cd /etc/yum.repos.d/ && \
    sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' * && \
    sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' *

RUN yum install java -y

RUN mkdir /opt/tomcat
WORKDIR /opt/tomcat
ADD https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.1.13/bin/apache-tomcat-10.1.13.tar.gz .
RUN tar -xvzf apache-tomcat-10.1.13.tar.gz
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-10.1.13/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

but when i try to run the resulting image i get this (result are from `docker ps -a`

```
4343afc0a83e   mytomcat   "/opt/tomcat/apache-…"   20 seconds ago   Exited (1) 1     9 seconds ago             mytomcat-server
```

when i try to get more info by going into the logs by doing `docker logs mytomcat-server` i get :

```
Unrecognized option: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Also i have to specify that it's a docker host running on amzn2 on AWS EC2

I tried wiping the container and to relaunch it, tried a bunch of code fixes nothing really did anything. i don't have much info other than "fatal exception has occured" and `Unrecognized option: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED.` From what i can find online it's a version problem? I had problems when specifying the version of java while making my Dockerfile so i didn't specify the version in the file.

Comment: i added `FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim  RUN apt-get update && \     apt-get install -y wget` but i still have the same error and message in the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/migrate/migrating-jdk-8-later-jdk-releases.html#GUID-12F945EB-71D6-46AF-8C3D-D354FD0B1781

You should probably use jdk 17 or later if you have that switch set.

See to it the jdk is updated on the docker image.

Comment: i added 
`FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget`

now i have an error code (2)

edit : the error code changed but the message is the same

Answer (score 1):

I've changed my config to :

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget

WORKDIR /opt/tomcat
ADD https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.1.13/bin/apache-tomcat-10.1.13.tar.gz .
RUN tar -xvzf apache-tomcat-10.1.13.tar.gz && \
    mv apache-tomcat-10.1.13 tomcat

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/opt/tomcat/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

now it's up and running and seems functional